# На странице тревог нет перевода для harassment/bigotry/abuse

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, тревоги

На [странице тревог участника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/213987) (переход [из профиля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213987/a-k) по клику на тревогах) не все новые типы тревог переведены:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перевод был добавлен и вскоре отобразится на сайте.

> выражает нетерпимость, связан с травлей или оскорбителен